# Sorting items In NSDictionary

Tags: nsdictionary

I am reading the items from plist into dictionary, i am using keys of dictionary to set title and value as tag to the buttons. now i have to sort the items in the dictionary, i don't want to put sorted items into array, as i am using dictionary to set title and tag for the button. I checked the links but most of them are putting sorted items into array. How can i do it with out using array , and instead use same dictionary.
here is code snippet.

```
while (key = [keyEnumerator nextObject])
{
    UIButton *btnWith = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btnWith.tag = [[topics objectForKey:key] integerValue] ;
    [btnWith setTitle:key forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnWith.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Aller-Light" size:15];
    [btnWith setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnWith.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [btnWith setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnWith addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckboxClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.scrollview setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, topics.count *50)];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of a dictionary's entries is not defined. You have to sort the keys (e.g. with any of the sortXXX [methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keysSortedByValueUsingSelector%3a)) and save them in a collection which is ordered (e.g. an array).
Then use this collection to access the dictionary entries in your desired order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer DAXaholic.. Are there alternative solution for this?

Comment: I suppose you worry about performance / unnecessary overhead, but if your dictionary is not extremely large and you don't access it every few msecs then don't prematurely optimize this way. Maybe you want to add a category to NSDictionary to hide the extra detour over arrays to make your code more readable. So to answer your question directly: I don't know of another solution for your problem but I don't think that this approach will be a big problem for your app.